# Keycloak ClassCastException in isValid() method

Tags: java, keycloak, classcastexception

I'm running a Keycloak server inside a Docker container. Then I programmed a custom User Storage Provider to check for authentication.

The problem is that in my CredentialInputValidator implementation the method

```
public boolean isValid(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, CredentialInput credentialInput)
```

is called with an instance of org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter as second parameter (userModel).

I expect a MyCustomUserModel instance instead, which is what the method

```
public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm)
```

is returning. So I try to cast userModel to MyCustomUserModel and it throws the following exception:

> Uncaught server error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter cannot be cast to
> class com.package.MyCustomUserModel
> (org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserAdapter is in unnamed module
> of loader 'org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@11.0.0' @35823d20;
> com.package.MyCustomUserModel is in unnamed module of loader
> 'deployment.keycloak_custom_ext_ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.keycloak_custom_ext-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
> @139eb90f)

In fact using other Keycloak server that I used in other tests the very same User Storage Provider is working as expected (an instance of MyCustomUserModel).

Maybe I'm failing at configuring the Keycloak server but I have no clue what option could be involved. Any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the cache policy. In Keycloak's admin application, under the User Federation section, edited my User Storage Provider and selected NO_CACHE as Cache Policy.

The ClassCastException does not appear anymore.

I guess I'll need to struggle a bit more on this if I need caching in the future.

Comment: Did you get something with cache policy?

Comment: I didn't find anything.

Comment: I am struggling with setting up keycloak 20 (quarkas based distribution) in clustering mode along with independent infispan clustor. I cant find anything useful in the documentation. Can you help in this?

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with Keycloak for the last three years. Anyway never worked with clustering mode.